# Проверка на true @ false

Tags: java, android, functional-buttons

Имеем следующий код:

```
Quest[] statements = new Quest[3];

private void fillQuestions() {
    statements[0] = new Quest("Столица России - это Казань", false);
    statements[1] = new Quest("Камень крепкий", true);
    statements[2] = new Quest("Музыка - это прекрасно", true);
}

private void textShow() {
    TextView qustions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statements);
    qustions.setText(statements[0].statement);
    Button btnTrue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_true);
    Button btnFalse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lie);
    btnTrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Угадал!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    btnFalse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Не угадал!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Как сделать проверку на на правильность при ответе?

Comment: Очевидно вам надо где-то сохранять правильный ответ для текущего вопроса и в ClickListener проверять, что пользователь нажал правильную кнопку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что кнопка `btnTrue` соответствует значению, что утверждение в вопросе верное, а `btnFalse`- что неверное. При этом правильное значение хранится вторым параметром объекта `Quest` - так как из вашего вопроса не ясно, как называется это второе поле, я условно назвал его `valid` . Примерно как то так:

```
Quest[] statements = new Quest[3];

private void fillQuestions() {
    statements[0] = new Quest("Столица России - это Казань", false);
    statements[1] = new Quest("Камень крепкий", true);
    statements[2] = new Quest("Музыка - это прекрасно", true);
}

private void textShow() {
    TextView qustions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statements);
    qustions.setText(statements[0].statement);
    Button btnTrue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_true);
    Button btnFalse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lie);
    btnTrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isTrue(statements[0].valid);
        }
    });
    btnFalse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isTrue(!statements[0].valid);
        }
    });

  void isTrue( boolean isTrue){
    String valid = (isTrue) ? "Угадал!" : "Не угадал!";
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, valid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

Стоит заметить, что ваша реализация игры-викторины несколько неверная. С очень хорошими и подробнейшим образом разобранными примерами реализации игры-викторины вы можете ознакомится в книгах:

Брайн Харди , Билл Филипс - "Программирование под Android", 2014 г. - пример из этой книги - первое приложение "GeoQuiz"

П. Дейтел - "Android для программистов. Создаем приложения", 2012 г. - Глава 6: Приложение Flag Quiz Game

Comment: Огромное спасибо.